# How to reset page numbering in a thesis document

Tags: page-numbering

I am using a predefined document class that I downloaded from my school website to write my thesis. It creates the front page, table of contents, and then rest of the document in the given sequence. Page numbering starts from the first chapter. 
My school requires a scanned copy of a signed form right after the table of content. When I insert it, the page numbering starts from the page on which this figure (form takes a whole page) is inserted. I want page numbering to start from my first chapter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{gatech-thesis}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{thesis}
\begin{preliminary}
\contents
\end{preliminary}
\pagenumbering{gobble} 
\begin{figure}[htp] \centering{
\includegraphics[scale=0.80]{myfile.pdf}}
\end{figure}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{Introduction}\label{introduction}

\end{document}
```

Now page number is removed from the page on which I have inserted the figure, but the number '2' is showing up on the introduction section.

This means that `\setcounter{page}{1}` didn't work.

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide an MWE that can be compiled. As a minimum, you need to tell us the article class (probably `book`, but `scrbook` or others are also possible of course).

Comment: Your MWE still won't compile.

Comment: you don't need `\setcounter{page}{1}` at all try to delete it

Comment: In any case, the page number is incremented at the start of a page, so if you need to set the page counter, do it after \chapter.  The contents should reflect the page number at ship out time.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 25):

I don't know if this is still active, but actually I think that you should reset the counter exactly after the chapter title.

```
\chapter{Title}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

like so.

Comment: I like this answer, concise, to the point, and contains all information necessary.

Answer (score 8):

I think this might help. I have reset page counter just before chapter one. Hence chapter one starts at page number 1.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagenumbering{gobble} 

    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics{demo}
    \end{figure}

    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{0}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

When compiling this MWE, there is no page number on the first page, and there is the page number "1" on the second page of the document, which is the one with the "Introduction" chapter. I downloaded gatech-thesis.sty from the zip file at (1), and I also tried using the CTAN version at (2).

(1) http://www.grad.gatech.edu/theses-dissertations-templates

(2) https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gatech-thesis

```
\documentclass{gatech-thesis}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagenumbering{gobble} 

    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics{demo}
    \end{figure}

    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get using MiKTeX pdflatex on Windows:

[image]

Comment: this didn't work….Introduction is still starting from '2'

Comment: When you write "this doesn't work", you mean you compile the exact code that I posted in my answer, and your resulting file (pdf, for example) has a "2" typeset at the bottom of the second page?

Comment: yes….everything same except document class  \documentclass[12pt]{gatech-thesis}

Comment: "Our cars have the same color, except that mine is red and yours is green." Please see my comment to your question. One needs knowledge of the document class *as part of the question* because this determines 100% of the behavior of your document.

Comment: sorry about that….i have added it in original post

Comment: Try updating your TeX distribution. Although that would surprise me, both the CTAN version and the version at your university's web site are dated 2010.

Comment: I am an end user kind of person and i have not experimented much with this template……I will look into what it means to update TeX distribution and how can one do it

Comment: You will find much help here as soon as you let us know what kind of distribution you are using :)