# How to draw a rectangle with only "one" round edge

Tags: tikz-shape

I need to draw a rectangle with only one round edge like following image.

[image]

In this case its south-west corner that is round. I looked up n saw this post

[Draw a rectangle with rounded ends in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211342/draw-a-rectangle-with-rounded-ends-in-tikz)

but i got error when I did

> \node (1) [draw, draw, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle north east
>   arc=0pt] {rounded rectangle}

**which is modified version of (Answer 1: Line 11)**

> \node (2) [draw, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle west arc=0pt]
>   {rounded rectangle};

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? The question you linked to has 5 answers and you don't even tell us which one you tried nor how you modified it.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Can you please check if the answers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297639/36296, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297385/36296, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297230/36296, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297167/36296, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262259/36296,  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262256/36296, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262156/36296, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262071/36296, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255314/36296 solve your problem and accept them if they do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[sharp corners] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1)   -- (1,0) [rounded corners] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this looks good but I find specifying a rectangle by coordinates a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 6):

as node with such shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
oneroundedge/.style = {%
    minimum width=#1,
    minimum height=12mm, text depth=0.25ex,
    outer sep=0pt,
    append after command={
        \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
    \path[draw, fill=gray!30] (\LN.south west) -| (\LN.north east)
        -- (\LN.north west) [rounded corners=3mm] -- cycle;
                       }     },
        font=\bfseries}
                    ]
\node (n1) [oneroundedge=12mm] {};
\node (n2) [oneroundedge=22mm, right=of n1] {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

it is easy to add more options to `oneroundedge` style definition (for example for `fill`). solution with `node` enable all possibilities of nodes placement, anchoring etc. *note*: anchor `south west` is at south west corner of rectangle which underlay define  `oneroundedge` shape.

Answer (score 2):

if you do not need it filled it is possible with simple LaTeX commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\unitlength=1cm \thicklines
\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(8,4)
\put(8,4){\oval(16,8)[lb]}
\put(0,4){\line(1,0){8}}\put(8,0){\line(0,1){4}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A variation on samcarter's answer, without explicit coordinates of the path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm] (a) {};
    \draw[fill=black] (a.south west) -- (a.north west) -- (a.north east) -- (a.south east) [rounded corners=10pt] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I saw many accepted answers and decided to give you a solution:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}

          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[black,fill=gray] (0,0)--(3,0)--(3,-2)--(0.2,-2) to[in=270,out=180] (0,-1.8)--cycle;
          \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

It is a manual solution using the command "to" that I think is a useful command. I am sure there are better solution (So, don't accept it yet)